# Prevent DialogFragment from sending the app into energy save mode

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, android-wake-lock

I'm creating an App for an Android Wearable Device.

When showing a custom layout as a dialogue fragment, the app will get minimized (getting replaced by the watch face) after about 30 seconds. I know that this is supposed to be the default behavior of apps out of touch with their users, but in my case, the app needs to stay visible even if not touched four minutes.

The Activities calling it did get these instructions inside their `onCreate` implementation.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

that works like a charm and in the way I want it. However, the DialogFragment that serves as an error notification (and may need to get observed without touching it for some time) does not obey this setting.

I tried to get the flag inside the `DialogFragment` too by placing it inside the `onViewCreated` calls, but it does not have the `getWindow` Method. While the next code segment is valid, is does not work either.

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The way the dialog fragment is called looks like this. That's the code to call it from the FragmentActivity needing to show it. As you might notice, there is a field "activity", which is because the whole call is done from a static class outside the activity. I want to call the same DialogFragment from multiple activities, with only the text and the title being different.

```java
   public static void showDialogCuston(String title, String message, FragmentActivity activity){

        ErrorDialogFragment edf = ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(title,message);

        FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        edf.show(fm, "TAG");
    }
```

And that's what the DialogFragment does look like inside. I kicked out all `TextView` text assignments because I doubt that they could offer any kind of information about that request, and just making the code fragment less readable.

```java
public class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    //some private text views
    public ErrorDialogFragment(){

    }

    public static ErrorDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String text){
        ErrorDialogFragment edf = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title",title);
        args.putString("text",text);
        edf.setArguments(args);
        return edf;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error, container, false);
        // R.layout.fragment_error is the layout that serves as my custom dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        //assigning layout elements to private fields
        //assigning stuff from the bundle inside some textViews

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
                //playing a sound from SoundPool and doing haptic feedback on button press
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, all I want is that the app won't disappear by itself when one is staring too long on the `DialogFragment` without touching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would like to suggest keeping the screen-on flag in the dialog layout file so that when the dialog view is visible, it keeps the screen on. Check the [developer's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) for more information. However, I am adding the code from the documentation for convenience.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the `android:keepScreenOn` to `true` in the root element of your dialog layout. And I hope you also have the following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Hey, I think this is one of the ways to go around it. Can you make sure the link works? For some weird reason, it is blocked

Comment: Yea, it's OK now. I also don't think you need the permission in this case. As the documentation points out, this doesn't need special permissions

Comment: Damn, once I was on this page to gather information about how to invoke this from Java code's side. I totally forgot about the alternative inside the xml. Tanks for pointing out! Right now, said DialogFragment is onScreen since over three minutes, which fulfils the requirement in every way! By the way, I didn't get why code highlighting inside the question didn't work. What did you change, it somehow looks the same

Comment: Great to know that I could help! I tried to format your question so that it well readable to other people who are trying to help you. :)